# How to finance and structure an easy knockoffable business idea of a dummy poor 19 yo?

Tags: financial-literacy, small-business, business, financing

I am a poor 19yo, found one probably original business idea of products that will help (not entertain) people. However I am absolutely not savvy in technical business knowledge, so please answer my few problem questions of not understanding.

That business will not have any patents or other protection, because of consisting of only few unique processes and also based on the processes products in sales funnel (with reselling) and marketing. So probably it should be launched and expanding marketing and brand dominance as soon as possible. With that, I think it's very possible to establish some few years niche positioning as demand/desire of market for business'es offerings will be there probably for years at least internationally and for poor communities everywhere.

Correspondingly I should have all the necessary and advantageous/preferred preparations before going to funders/financers and/or talented partners/team/workers.

Please tell me what are some best options in my situations for:

1. finding financing/funding. Reminder: going and pitching to everyone my idea will probably create betterly positioned already savvy competitors, establishing their knockoff/clone business within a week or even a few days.
2. deciding corporate/organizational structure.

I'm absolutely ready for significant payment of new company's equity; or getting a big loan (maybe with credentials of a talented team as I'm dirt poor?); or with big equity riskingly relying (and asking them for doing a lot of necessary stuff) on one or few talented investors as partners (as I'm a complete novice with just somewhat goodly developed model from all compatible/advantageous sides available to business in limits of those processes, products in types for funneling, some website idea, marketing, strategy for survival and development).

I'm in Russian Federation by they way, and dirt poor, but ready to go anywhere with english with money to do so (like maybe after a little success).

What I should do actually in those 2 questions considering my situation?

Comment: It can be a long journey!  Whenever you talk to anyone about it (such as here) it is like ripples in a pond going outwards!  Good luck, keep communicating!

Answer (score 2):

Q1) You won't be able to find one penny of financing. Find another way to begin organically.

Q2) I would really just find "some way" to get established in a country like UK or US, make it happen through marriage or whatever. Get a job while you slowly establish your business idea.

Regarding corporate structure, it's totally irrelevant until you grow a little, just act as a sole trader.

Good luck!

Comment: I was going to offer to send OP $1 just to disprove your first point. Then I realized that would just be the exception that proves the rule, so you'd be right AND I'd be out $1.

Answer (score 1):

If the business development is vague on this forum then when and where is it not vague ?

If the business development has unique processes then why isn't it interested in patent protection ?

But the business development says that it is for poor communities. Well, find established businesses in target communities who will offer the product and who will pay a percentage of sales. That's a franchise model. In a franchise model, the partner company is regularly provided with something that it needs. Also, the partner company benefits from a trademark branding that is widely marketed for them. The first step it to get a trademark.

Also, N.V. Netherlands incorporation is popular in western Europe.